# Stop Workflows overriding values

Tags: list, workflow

Two of my columns in a risk/issue list - Project ID and Project Title should update each other based on the values entered, these values are coming from another reference list where ID and Project title are maintained on a 1:1 basis per entry for example.

If I enter "01" in Project ID - Project Title is updated to "Test Project". If I entered "Test Project" Project ID should update to "01"

My problem is seemingly both workflows overriding each other when I maintain two separate Update Item in Current Item.

Should I use if statements to separate the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..This is making the task complex.based on the item modified it is performing both the action. Its better to integrate the action under one workflow. Use if else and staging under one workflow